# Transpose of Selector Matrix [Introduction to Applied Linear Algebra]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to check my answer to an exercise (7.5) in Boyd's Introduction to Applied Linear Algebra:

> Suppose the $m \times n$ matrix $A$ is a selector matrix. Describe the relation between the $m$-vector $u$ and the $n$-vector $v = A^Tu$.

The definition of a selector matrix given earlier in the chapter is

> An $m \times n$ selector matrix is one in which each row is a unit vector (transposed): $$ A = \begin{bmatrix} e_{k_1}^T \\ \vdots \\ e_{k_m}^T \end{bmatrix} $$ 
>   where $k_1, \dots, k_m$ are integers in the range $1, \dots, n$.

**My solution so far:** According to my calculation, $A_{ij} = e_{k_1} \cdot e_{k_j}$, which is 1 if $k_i = k_j$ and 0 otherwise. This means that $AA^T$ has 1s on the diagonal and 0s otherwise, i.e. $AA^T = I$. Thus, $Av = AA^Tu = u$, so it seems that $A^T$ has the effect of inverting the selection operation.

**What I don't understand is:** How we could recover a specific vector $v$ using $A^T$ on $u$. Suppose, for example, that $u = (1, 2, 3)$, $n = 5$, and $A$ selects elements 1, 3, and 5 of any vector from $\mathbb{R}^5$. Then couldn't the recovered vector be either $v_1 = (1, 1, 2, 2, 3)$ or $v_2 = (1, 10, 2, 10, 3)$? In these cases $Av_1 = Av_2 = u$.

I'm definitely missing something - but what?

Comment: I don’t understand why you think your answer is wrong? It seems like you just explained it correctly. Also what do you mean by recovering $v$ using $A^\top$? You mean you want a vector $v$ such that $A^\top v=v$? I don’t think that’s possible, simply because $A$ isn’t square, and thus corresponds to a linear transformation between two different vector spaces.

Comment: @hasManyStupidQuestions, thanks for the comment! I guess the problem I have is: Let's say we start off with some vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We compute $u = Av \in \mathbb{R}^m$ ($m \leq n$). Now we compute $A^Tu = A^TAv = v$. Mathematically, it makes sense, but I'm not sure I conceptually understand how applying $A^T$ can recover the elements from $v$ that we dropped when we computed $u$.

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer; this might be more helpful than what I wrote originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(The following assumes that $A$ has full rank, ie that the rows are linearly independent when $m \le n$, or that the columns are linearly independent when $n \le m$.)

If $m \le n$, then $AA^\top$ is the identity on $\mathbb{R}^m$, and $A^\top A$ is a projection onto an $m$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If $n \le m$, then $AA^\top$ is a projection onto an $n$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$, and $A^\top A$ is the identity on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Specifically, the argument given above which claims that $A^\top A$ is the identity implicitly assumes that $n \le m$. Can you figure out where?

*EDIT:* Note that $A^\top$ is $n \times m$, and $$ A^\top = \begin{bmatrix} e_{k_1} & \cdots & e_{k_m} \end{bmatrix} $$ 
where $k_1, \dots, k_m$ are integers in the range $1, \dots, n$.

Then $A^\top u$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A^\top$ where the coefficients are the entries of $u$:

$$ A^\top u = \sum_{i=1}^m u_i \begin{bmatrix} e_{k_i} \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: Yes, you're right, I can see where I did it. I just worked through an example, and I think a more accurate explanation of what $A^T$ does is that it produces a vector that matches the original $v$ in the selected indices with 0s in the locations that were selected out. Does that make sense?

Comment: @jeg That sounds close, although I think it involves a counting argument and can still be different between the two cases $m\le n$ or not. Please see the edit to this answer. Is that more helpful? If so, please don’t forget to accept the answer. (Also note that it’s generally true of matrix vector multiplication that the result is a linear combination of the columns of the matrix using the entries of the coefficients. I personally find this way of thinking about it is more often helpful than the commonly presented way.)